# How to fix the R/exams error "could not find function answerlist"

Tags: r-exams

I have created an R/exams question in R/Markdown format. When I try to compile and then take it to `exams2moodle` and / or `exams2pdf`, I get the following error message:

> Error in answerlist (questions, markup = "markdown"): could not find function answerlist.

The exercise is:

````
```{r, data generation, echo = FALSE, results = "hide"}
#1a.GENERACION DE DATOS. ASIGNACION/DEFINICION DE VARIABLES. CUELLO
a1<-sample(seq(from = 100, to = 250, by = 2), 10)
casilla1<-min(a1)
casilla2<-max(a1)
increm<-casilla2-casilla1
a2<-sample(seq(from = casilla2, to = casilla2+increm, by = 2))
casilla3<-min(a2)
casilla4<-max(a2)
a3<-sample(seq(from = casilla4, to = casilla4+increm, by = 2))
casilla5<-min(a3)
casilla6<-max(a3)

#1b.GENERACION DE DATOS. ASIGNACION/DEFINICION DE VARIABLES. CUERPO
crpizq<-casilla6*1.5
c1<-sample(seq(from = crpizq, to = crpizq+increm, by = 2))
casilla7<-min(c1)
casilla8<-max(c1)
c2<-sample(seq(from = casilla8, to = casilla8+increm, by = 2))  
casilla9<-min(c2)
casilla10<-max(c2)
c3<-sample(seq(from = casilla10, to = casilla10+increm, by = 2))
casilla11<-min(c3)
casilla12<-max(c3)

#1c.GENERACION DE DATOS. ASIGNACION/DEFINICION DE VARIABLES. PRECIO
precio1<-sample(seq(from=20000, to=40000, by=500), 1)
precio2<-precio1+15000
precio3<-precio2+15000
preciopregunta<-sample(c(precio1,precio2,precio3), 1)

#2a.GENERACION DE PREGUNTA(S)/RESPUESTA(S). ASIGNACION/DEFINICION DE VARIABLES
cuellop1<-sample(seq(from = casilla1,to = casilla2-1, by = 2), 1)
cuerpop1<-sample(seq(from = casilla7,to = casilla8-1, by = 2), 1)
cuellop2<-sample(seq(from = casilla3,to = casilla4-1, by = 2), 1)
cuerpop2<-sample(seq(from = casilla9,to = casilla10-1, by = 2), 1)
cuellop3<-sample(seq(from = casilla5,to = casilla6-1, by = 2), 1)
cuerpop3<-sample(seq(from = casilla11,to = casilla12-1, by = 2), 1)

questions<-solutions<-explanations<-NULL
if(preciopregunta==precio1) {
   questions[1]<-paste("Vasija de " ,cuellop1, " mm en contorno de cuello y ", 
                    cuerpop1, " mm en contorno de cuerpo.")
   solutions[1]<-TRUE
   explanations[1]<-"."
   questions[2]<-paste("Vasija de " ,cuellop1, " mm en contorno de cuello y ", 
                    cuerpop2, " mm en contorno de cuerpo.")
   solutions[2]<-FALSE
   explanations[2]<-"."
   questions[3]<-paste("Vasija de " ,cuellop2, " mm en contorno de cuello y ", 
                    cuerpop3, " mm en contorno de cuerpo.")
   solutions[3]<-FALSE
   explanations[3]<-"."
   questions[4]<-paste("Vasija de " ,casilla1, " mm en contorno de cuello y ", 
                    casilla8, " mm en contorno de cuerpo.")
   solutions[4]<-FALSE
   explanations[4]<-"."
   orden<-sample(1:4)
   questions<-questions[orden]
   solutions<-solutions[orden]
   explanations<-explanations[orden]
   } else if (preciopregunta==precio2) {
   questions[1]<-paste("Vasija de " ,cuellop2, " mm en contorno de cuello y ", 
                    cuerpop2, " mm en contorno de cuerpo.")
   solutions[1]<-TRUE
   explanations[1]<-"."
   questions[2]<-paste("Vasija de " ,cuellop1, " mm en contorno de cuello y ", 
                    cuerpop2, " mm en contorno de cuerpo.")
   solutions[2]<-FALSE
   explanations[2]<-"."
   questions[3]<-paste("Vasija de " ,cuellop2, " mm en contorno de cuello y ", 
                    cuerpop3, " mm en contorno de cuerpo.")
   solutions[3]<-FALSE
   explanations[3]<-"."
   questions[4]<-paste("Vasija de " ,casilla3, " mm en contorno de cuello y ", 
                    casilla10, " mm en contorno de cuerpo.")
   solutions[4]<-FALSE
   explanations[4]<-"."
   orden<-sample(1:4)
   questions<-questions[orden]
   solutions<-solutions[orden]
   explanations<-explanations[orden]
   } else {
   questions[1]<-paste("Vasija de " ,cuellop3, " mm en contorno de cuello y ", 
                    cuerpop3, " mm en contorno de cuerpo.")
   solutions[1]<-TRUE
   explanations[1]<-"."
   questions[2]<-paste("Vasija de " ,cuellop1, " mm en contorno de cuello y ", 
                    cuerpop2, " mm en contorno de cuerpo.")
   solutions[2]<-FALSE
   explanations[2]<-"."
   questions[3]<-paste("Vasija de " ,cuellop2, " mm en contorno de cuello y ", 
                    cuerpop3, " mm en contorno de cuerpo.")
   solutions[3]<-FALSE
   explanations[3]<-"."
   questions[4]<-paste("Vasija de " ,casilla5, " mm en contorno de cuello y ", 
                    casilla12, " mm en contorno de cuerpo.")
   solutions[4]<-FALSE
   explanations[4]<-"."
   orden<-sample(1:4)
   questions<-questions[orden]
   solutions<-solutions[orden]
   explanations<-explanations[orden] }
```
The table shows the relationship between prices and measurements that an artisan handles in the sale of vessels:

|       Contorno del cuello (mm)        |        Contorno del cuerpo (mm)         |       Precio        |
|:-------------------------------------:|:---------------------------------------:|:-------------------:|
| [**`r casilla1`** , **`r casilla2`**) |  [**`r casilla7`** , **`r casilla8`**)  | $\$$**`r precio1`** |
| [**`r casilla3`** , **`r casilla4`**) | [**`r casilla9`** , **`r casilla10`**)  | $\$$**`r precio2`** |
| [**`r casilla5`** , **`r casilla6`**) | [**`r casilla11`** , **`r casilla12`**) | $\$$**`r precio3`** |

Question
========

Which of the following pots has a price of $\$$**`r preciopregunta`**?

```{r, questionlist, echo = FALSE, results = "asis"}
answerlist(questions, markup = "markdown")
```

Solution
========
```{r, solutionlist, echo = FALSE, results = "asis"}
answerlist(ifelse(solutions,"True","False"),explanations, markup = "markdown")
```

Meta-information
================
extype: schoice 
exsolution:`r mchoice2string(solutions)` 
exname: Vas
````

Comment: Thanks!!! You are the best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot replicate this problem using the exercise you provided, for me the code works. You should move the text with the table into the `Question` section, though.

What might have caused the problem is that you did not fully load and attach the R package `exams` via `library("exams")` and only used the fully-qualified `exams::exams2pdf(...)` without attaching the package. If so, then you also need the fully-qualified `exams::answerlist(...)` and `exams::mchoice2string(...)` etc. to use the functions from the package. (Personally, I load and attach the package with `library("exams")` before compiling any exercises.)

Comment: Hello. I forgot to post the seed code: library("exams")
library("stringr") 
library("tinytex")
library("rmarkdown")
setwd("SoloeRRe")
dir()


#Fijamos la semilla para la generación  
#de datos aleatorios (opcional):

#set.seed(1080) 

#Generamos una copia de masvasijas
#(exams2pdf, exams2html o exams2moodle):

exams2pdf("VasijasVasijas.Rmd",encoding="UTF-8",n=5)

ee<-exams_eval(rule="none")
exams2moodle("VasijasVasijas.Rmd",encoding="UTF-8",n=5,name="Vasijasghg",mchoice=list(eval=ee)) 

setwd("SoloeRRe")
dir()

Comment: Thanks for the code. I guess the only bit that would be needed here is `library("exams")` and then `exams2pdf("VasijasVasijas.Rmd")` if you are in the right directory. As indicated before, this all works without problems with me. Please make sure that you have current versions of R, exams, knitr, and rmarkdown installed and try again.

Comment: Did you try to run your example with the most current versions of R and all packages involved? If so, did this change anything?

Comment: The solution was immediate. Thanks.

Comment: Great, thanks for the follow-up. Please also accept the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left. Then the question is flagged as solved here on StackOverflow. Thanks!